# Loading .js files per page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Loading `.js` files into one large file or loading each `.js` file that is required on certain pages.

Is it good practise to compile all javascript files required for pages, plugins and tools into one file main `.js` file and then load this file at page load, or is it better to have multiple `.js` files for each plugin and each page that needs a particular `.js` file/s  you load what is required?

Comment: For development having each is a lot easier to debug. For production you could minify them into a single file so that they can be fetched over the network in a single request.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `.js` files that are common to all or at least most pages, then yes, load it into one file. If each page uses a separate `.js`, which is unusual, then you should load each file separately when it's needed.

This gets to be a problem if you have a lot of files which cause a lot of requests. You can use tools that automatically minify and compile your files into one tiny file as well. But this shouldn't be your main focus, as there are much larger issues with performance out there.

Comment: I use a compiler with gulp. Lets say a compiled file loads in at 400kb, it contains all plugins and code required for the website, however only a few pages required some of the scripts inside it.

Comment: 400kb shouldn't be the reason you're staying up at night... Better that than a bunch of new requests since it will probably get cached anyways and be used on all the pages.

Comment: @Esotericist May be you could use require js library, which does the same thing as you require.

Comment: Very large website, it's done with bootstrap, but needs extend plugin for more functionality. However, these combined with css compiled and loading in on page load, needs a faster load time. Just needed to know if it's good practise or not, compiling or separately loading in

Comment: Compiling is the best practice. However, it sorta depends on your site. I would change my focus to other things (like images) that I'm sure are slowing you down more.

Comment: huge website, e.commerce store with 1000+ products. However, I've always had the belief that 400kb + 200kb css files + 100kb jquery it makes for a very large load time. Wouldn't splitting them up per page be best in this situation?

Comment: If you can separate the functionality needed in each page and correlate that to individual js files, then go for it. But keep those minified and try to combine as many as you can so you have as close to one file load per page - where possible.

Answer (score 0):

It does not really matter as the files are fairly small compared to images.

Also they can be cached.

So do whatever is easier.